# TinyMCE 4 custom file picker return value from popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like to implement custom file picker to TinyMCE 4, but i dont know how to return value from second popup window.

Here is my code:

```js
textTiny.settings.file_picker_callback = function(callback, value, meta) {
  imageFilePicker(callback, value, meta);
};

var imageFilePicker = function (callback, value, meta) {               
  tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    title: 'Photo picker',
    url: "files-list.html",
    width: $(window).width() * 0.8,
    height: $(window).height() * 0.8,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Insert',
      onclick: function () {
        var file_src = $(".photo.selected").attr("href");
        callback(file_src);
        tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
      }
    }, 
    {
      text: 'Close',
      onclick: 'close'
    }],
  });
};
```

I will appreciate any advice.
Thank you.

Comment: What did you tried? You just give us your code with a message "I'd like to do this" but what doesn't work?

Comment: That jQuery selector "$(".photo.selected")" doesn't work. Returns undefined value. My JS/jQuery skills are not so good, but I think that is because tinyMCE insert for popup iframe with whole new HTML document. So I think that jQuery selector is not best way to get value, but I didn't find another way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could start by going to TinyMce website. They have a demo tab where you can find a code snippet for implement basic local file picker [here](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/file-picker/)